# Is there any connector to run code in logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Azure.
Is there any connector to run code snippet instead of inline code and azure function?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and write more detail about what you want to archieve?

Comment: Why are those two options not enough for you?

Comment: Definitely need more detail to effectively answer. My best guess is your scenario rules one of these out for some reason. Depending on your environment/requirements, you could also use Stored Procedures, call a REST endpoint, execute a Data Factory pipeline, or use Azure Batch to run custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the two ways in which you can have your custom logic/code to run. Another way is to create custom connectors and publish them. You can utilize it in the pipeline created with logic apps